# Sentence structure analysis

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am trying to look at the structure similarity of sentences, specifically to the position of verbs, adj, nouns.
For instance, I have three (or more) sentences which look likes as follows:

```
I ate an apple pie, yesterday. 
I ate an orange, yesterday.
I eat a lemon, today.
```

All of them starts with a pronoun (I) followed by a verb (ate/eat) and a noun (apple pie, orange, lemon) and, finally, an adverb (yesterday/tomorrow).

I would like to know if there is a way to identify the structure, i.e. PRONOUN VERB NOUN ADVERB in the sentence.

If I think of it as a pandas dataframe:

```
SENTENCE
    I ate an apple pie, yesterday. 
    I ate an orange, yesterday.
    I eat a lemon, today.
```

I would need to have something like as follows:

```
SENTENCE                                    STRUCTURE
    I ate an apple pie, yesterday.        PRONOUN VERB NOUN ADJECTIVE
    I ate an orange, yesterday.           PRONOUN VERB NOUN ADJECTIVE         
    I eat a lemon, today.                 PRONOUN VERB NOUN ADJECTIVE
```

Do you know how I can get this (or similar) results?

Comment: You are not looknig for the structure of the text, you rather want to know about part of speech tagging, from which you can derive a rule for a simple phrase structure grammar. If you want to compare structures really, then you need a measure to compare parsing trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example using spacy:

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd

# load english language model
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm',disable=['ner','textcat'])

text = "I ate an apple pie, yesterday."

# create spacy 
doc = nlp(text)
pos = ""
for token in doc:
    pos += token.pos_ + " "
    
# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([[text, pos]], columns=['Sentence', 'Structure'])
print(df)
```

Output is:

```
                      Sentence                                  Structure
0  I ate an apple pie, yesterday.  PRON VERB DET NOUN NOUN PUNCT NOUN PUNCT
```