# Getting sentence structure in a column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, spacy

I am finding some difficulties in apply the following code to one column in my dataset:

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm',disable=['ner','textcat'])

def f(text):
    pos = ""
    for token in text:
        pos += token.pos_ + " "
    return pos

df['Structure']= df.Low_Sentences.str.apply(f)
```

Where `Low_Sentences` is something like this:

```
Low_Sentences

A sentence is a set of words that is complete in itself
Seeing a specific word used in a sentence can provide more context and help you better understand proper usage.
Short example: She walks.
```

But I am getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'apply'

Can you please tell me how to apply that function in order to get the structure of each row in my dataframe? Thanks

Comment: what is `pos_`? If `text` is a string, `token` is also a string and there is no `pos_` method defined for a string

Comment: I am trying to use this algorithm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63763542/sentence-structure-analysis but for each row, not only for a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the str conversion. In pandas you apply on the columns.

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm',disable=['ner','textcat'])

def f(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    pos = ""
    for token in doc:
        pos += token.pos_ + " "
    return pos

df['Structure']= df.Low_Sentences.apply(f)
```

FYI: You had forgotten the `doc = nlp(text)` line!!

Comment: I got this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pos_'

Comment: Your `f` function is incorrect
What exactly are you trying to do with your function?

Comment: What is pos-tagging?
Please describe your question in detail with appropriate examples, people can help you only when they have the complete context

Comment: I am trying to apply this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63763542/sentence-structure-analysis but for each row

Comment: Ok, you just missed out a very important line from that above source: `doc = nlp(text)`

Comment: Updated the answer, try it now